# Enlarge the dimension of a matrix by adding trivial 0 entries

Tags: numpy

I'm using `np.array` for matrix computation. Now I have a [2,2] matrix,`A=[[0, 1], [1,0]]`, and now I would like to express A in higher dimension from [2,2] to, saying, [5,5] by adding 1 in diagonal of higher dimension.

For instance,

```
A-> B 
=[
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
```

At present, I use my own means by

1. pulling out the rows of A. e.g. [0, 1] and append 0 to expected length->[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
2. preparing extra zero rows `np.zeros(wanted_dim)` and assemble them

> ```
>  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
>  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
>  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
>  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
>  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> ```

3. adding 1 in diagonal entries

which is not quite neat, so I would like to ask is there any np.method to implement such function? By taking A and the wanted dimension as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
def expand(x, m, k):
    y = np.eye(m, k, dtype=x.dtype)
    y[0:x.shape[0], 0:x.shape[1]] = x
    return y
```